# como renderizar unicode corretamente

Tags: css, css3, unicode

boa tarde a todos!!!
Galera, seguinte, eu tenho o seguinte código "&#x25Bc" ele tem que renderizar no navegador uma seta para cima...porém, ao lançar no "content" do before, ele renderiza exatamente esses caracteres e não o simbolo de seta... o que pode ser a causa disso? codificação do editor de texto? sintaxe? o que sugerem?
segue o trecho que eu usei no before...

```
before{content: '\&#x25Bc';}
```

também tentei variações...

```
before{content: "\&#x25Bc";}
```

e nada do simbolo aparecer...

Answer (score 1):

Utilizei outro código para colocar a seta

```css
.teste::before{
  content: "\2191";
}
```

```html
<div class="teste">
</div>
```

Utilizei esta [lista](https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/), caso você não queira esta seta é só verificar a [lista](https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/) e alterar no seu código.

Answer (score 1):

Cara na verdade vc precisa "escapar" o Unicode hexadecimal com uma contra barra **`\`**

**Então o seu Unicode escapado ficaria assim:** `&#x25Bc` = `\25Bc` ou `\0025Bc` <sub>(4 ou 6 digitos)</sub> 
*Link de referencia desse unicode*: http://www.codetable.net/hex/25bc
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o que diz a **W3C**

> CSS represents escaped characters in a different way. Escapes start with a backslash followed by the hexadecimal number that represents the character's hexadecimal Unicode code point value.

PORTUGUÊS
*"CSS representa caracteres de `escape` de uma maneira diferente. `Escapes` começam com uma **barra invertida** seguida pelo número hexadecimal que representa o valor hexadecimal do ponto de código Unicode do caractere."*

Link oficial da **W3C** sobre o assunto: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#cssescapes

```css
.icon::before{
  content: "\25Bc";
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
(&#x25Bc) = &#x25Bc; = content: "\25Bc";
```